# No module named 'pandastable'

Tags: pandas, tkinter, module, anaconda, python-import

I'm trying to change table wrote by me on tkinter with the pandastable one in order to do the handling of data directly from a pandas.DataFrame.
But despite I have already installed Anaconda3 with matlplotlib, numpy, pandas ect. modules when i would like to import pandastable I have trouble. 
This is the problem:

```
import pandastable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandastable
ImportError: No module named 'pandastable'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install pandastable
```

Requires python>=3.3 or 2.7 and numpy, matplotlib and pandas.
See: [pandastable on github](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable)

edit: You may have multiple Python environments installed on your machine. Anaconda uses `conda install` to keep things in check but pandastable doesn't seem to be available through Anaconda packages. Make sure you are installing to the same Python environment that your script uses. You might also try:
`pip3 install pandastable`

Comment: I tryed but nothing. I fixed installing Pyrhon 3.6 and typing another time the cmd pip3 install pandastable. Now, it seems to work nice.